# How to set flag based on values in previous columns in same table ? (Oracle)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm creating a new table and carrying over several columns from a previous table. One of the new fields that I need to create is a flag that will have values 0 or 1 and value needs to be determined based on 6 previous fields in the table.

The 6 previous columns have preexisting values of 0 or 1 stored for each one. This new field needs to check whether any of the 6 columns have 1 and if so set the flag to 0. If there is 0 in all 6 fields then set itself to 1.

Hopefully this makes sense. How can I get this done in oracle? I assume a case statement and some sort of forloop?

Comment: Please, clarify *previous*: what is ordered and in which way to call it *previous*. May it be some columns of previous row or some columns of the same row that are after some specific column? For both the cases you need to define order: neither rows in table are ordered nor columns in table are ordered as well

Answer (score 2):

You can use a virtual column with a case expression; something like:

```
flag number generated always as (
  case when val_1 + val_2 + val_3 + val_4 + val_5 + val_6 = 0 then 1 else 0 end
) virtual
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=df8ffe79b7ee01f459376839c2f05008)

or the same thing [with `greatest()`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b4d928edb31f99e36c58a18b9d2af830) as @Sayan suggested.

Using a virtual column means the flag will be right for newly-inserted rows, and if any of the other values are updated; you won't have to recalculate or update the flag column manually.

I've assumed the other six columns can't be null and are constrained to only be 0 or 1, as the question suggests. If they can be null you can add `nvl()` or `coalesce()`  to each term in the calculation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `greatest()` function: [GREATEST](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/GREATEST.html)

```
create table t_new
as
select
   case when greatest(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6)=1 -- at least one of them contains 1
          then 0
          else 1
   end c_new
from t_old;
```

Or even shorter:

```
create table t_new
as
select
   1-greatest(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6) as c_new
from t_old;
```

In case of `greatest` = 1, `(1-1)=0`, otherwise `(1-0)=1`

Comment: Thank you for the help but I made a mistake. The preexisting values in the 6 columns are 'Y' for yes and 'N' for no. This possibly changes my question entirely as I cannot use the greatest function on a varchar

Comment: @valera_177 if you read the doc for greatest carefully, you'll find that it works for varchar2 too

Comment: @valera_177 you can easily check it using this query: `select greatest('N','Y','N','Y') gr from dual;`